# How to connect to Oracle database in docker through external applications like Pycharm?

Tags: python, database, oracle, docker, data-driven-tests

I am running tests using selenium with python in Pycharm. I want to automate and run tests using data from an oracle database (data driven testing). I don't have a database installed in my system .Will I be able to connect to oracle database in docker. Oracle Enterprise edition image is available in docker.So if I pull it and run it in my system through docker will I be able to connect to it through external applications like Pycharm.

Comment: If you map the correct ports or use `--net=host`, it should be fine.

Comment: Instead of installing Pycharm which is quite heavy software to run inside Docker, please consider making direct connection to Oracle e.g. using https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/ etc.

Comment: If you go with cx_Oracle, there are some Dockerfiles in https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1